# Chatterbot Installation

Tags: build, pip

I have been trying to install Chatterbot for the last 2 days but it keeps failing. I Am installing it in a conda environment using pip.
Here is the Error:

```
 Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2578 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (804 kB)
      Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
        Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
      Collecting Cython
        Using cached Cython-0.29.35-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
      Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
        Using cached cymem-2.0.7-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (34 kB)
      Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
        Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
        Using cached murmurhash-1.0.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (21 kB)
      Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
        Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached wasabi-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
      Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached srsly-1.0.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (209 kB)
      Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached numpy-1.25.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.6 MB)
      Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
      Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached tqdm-4.65.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: preshed, thinc, blis
        Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [218 lines of output]
            /home/chalo/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
            !!
      
                    ********************************************************************************
                    Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
                    If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
                    ********************************************************************************
```

Initially, I downgraded setuptools to version 58.2.0 but did not work. I have also installed cmake and downgraded pip too.
I also ran `pip install --use-pep517 setuptools` and got `requirement already satisfied`.
Here is an additional error message:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
        Running setup.py clean for blis
      Failed to build preshed thinc blis
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
```

Comment: 1. Don't do this in your base env, create a seperate env for chatterbot. 2. Have you tried `pip install --use-pep517 chatterbot`

Answer (score 1):

**I figured it out. It looks like Chatterbot does not support the current versions of Python, specifically > 3.8 versions.**

```
I created a new conda env: conda create -n chatterbot python=3.8
Installed chatterbot: pip install Chatterbot
```

**Visit: https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/** for more information about the requirements.